# Room Persistence library database is locked (code 5)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying for a longer time to find a solution for bypassing this issue or fix it but without the success.

I am using the latest version of the library **2.4.0-alpha04** because it provides AutoMigration and I found it pretty useful.
To short the story, I'm tracking logs for quite a long and seems that this happens only when the database is accessed at the same time from another context.

My application is using the DB inside the MainActivity and also in the foreground service which is a separated process.

I'm always thinking that problem lay there, but I am not sure. From the logs, issue happens when the service and the app try to write at the same time, where the service update the DB constantly.

```
companion object {
        private const val DATABASE = "BatteryInfoDatabase"
        private var instance: BatteryInfoDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context?): BatteryInfoDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(BatteryInfoDatabase::class.java) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context!!,
                            BatteryInfoDatabase::class.java, DATABASE)
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build()
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
```

This is a log output

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.paget96.batteryguru/activities.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode ################################################################# Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY) Caused By : The database file is locked. (database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode) #################################################################
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2695)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException
database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode ################################################################# Error Code : 5 (SQLITE_BUSY) Caused By : The database file is locked. (database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode) #################################################################
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (SQLiteConnection.java)
androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:482)
com.paget96.batteryguru.utils.database.batteryinfo.TemperatureHistoryDao_Impl.getTemperatureHistory (TemperatureHistoryDao_Impl.java:106)
com.paget96.batteryguru.utils.database.batteryinfo.BatteryInfoDatabase.getTemperatureHistory (BatteryInfoDatabase.java:76)
com.paget96.batteryguru.fragments.FragmentChargingInfo.temperatureHistoryChart (FragmentChargingInfo.java:247)
com.paget96.batteryguru.fragments.FragmentChargingInfo.initializeViews (FragmentChargingInfo.java:83)
com.paget96.batteryguru.fragments.FragmentChargingInfo.onViewCreated (FragmentChargingInfo.java:218)
androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated (Fragment.java:2985)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```